# The tab indent in emacs ipython shell

Tags: emacs, ipython

The environment is Emacs 24.1.1 on Ubuntu. using Ipython for python programming. 
The auto indent is works well when running ipython command on shell directly, but when i come to emacs run ipython there is no auto indent any more. and even worse when i type TAB it will prompt the *Completion* buffer.I also have searched this issue many times but still not found a practical method. as a result i have to enter space manually.

anyone could help to resolve this issue ? 
 1. auto indent on emacs ipython shell
 2. disable completion on emacs ipython shell separately.keep the Tab-completion work when i am not in ipython interactive shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In emacs you can use `python-mode`, and from there send the code to `*REPL*` buffer with <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd>.

When you send the buffer for the first time, it asks you what executable you use for python, so you can use ipython, or other one.

Comment: hi buddy, very thanks for your tips. I found the method i revoke ipython shell in emacs is wrong. in the past i first come to shell mode then type ipython base on the shell-mode. so it could this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Any invocation of ipython-shell should do a correct setup.
Please file a bug-report.

If running python-mode.el -- modeline shows "Py" --

please checkout current trunk first

When bazaar is available

bzr branch lp:python-mode